# Webpack. Использование autoprefixer с stylus

Tags: css, webpack, сборка, stylus

Решил добавить поддержку префиксов для различных браузеров в стилях. Для этого обратился к модулю [postcss-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader), на который многие ссылаются.

Адаптировал код из документации ([раз](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#webpack-1) и [два](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#webpack-1-1)) применительно к своему конфигу. Если правильно понял документацию, `postcss.config.js` необязателен, мы можем править конфиг вебпака

```js
let autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module: {
    loaders: [{
     test: /\.styl$/,
     loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!postcss!stylus?resolve url')
    }]
  },

  postcss: () => {
    return [autoprefixer];
  },
```

Но файл стилей собирается без префиксов. Где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку autoprefixer это postcss-плагин, его нужно вызвать как функцию:

```
return [autoprefixer()];
```

Comment: забавно, бандл стал собираться дольше, но префиксы все равно не появились

Comment: @while1pass а вы правильно настроили postcss-loader? Посмотрите как это делать для [webpack 2](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#webpack-2-1)

Comment: у меня первый вебпак, да, сделал по докам, в вопросе приведен конфиг, правда, для stylus файлов